# R: Creating a column with multiple variable names when their freq==1

Tags: r

The below is sample data and its table.

```
sample<-data.frame(mon=c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Jan","Feb","Mar","Jan","Feb","Mar"), 
             fruit=c("Orange","Orange",NA, "Apple",NA,"Apple",NA,"Berry","Berry"))
sample%>%{table(.$mon, .$fruit)}
      Apple Berry Orange
  Feb     0     1      1
  Jan     1     0      1
  Mar     1     1      0
```

How to create a data frame that collect variable names when their freq == 1  as below?

```
  mon     types
  Jan     Orange, Apple    
  Feb     Orange, Berry
  Mar     Apple, Berry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do a `group_by` `paste` after removing the `NA` elements with `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
sample %>% 
  filter(!is.na(fruit)) %>% 
  group_by(mon) %>% 
  summarise(types = toString(unique(fruit)))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  mon   types        
#  <fct> <chr>        
#1 Feb   Orange, Berry
#2 Jan   Orange, Apple
#3 Mar   Apple, Berry
```

---

Assuming that the OP create a `table` object, then we can convert to `data.frame`, `filter` the elements where 'Freq' is > 0 and use the same code

```
out <- sample%>%
          {table(.$mon, .$fruit)}
as.data.frame(out) %>% 
    filter(as.logical(Freq)) %>%  
    group_by(mon = Var1) %>% 
    summarise(types  = toString(unique(Var2)))
```